# view cv::Mat data while debugging in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, opencv, debugging, visual-studio-code, mat

I need to check elements of some `cv::Mat`s while debugging my OpenCV C++ code.

Tried adding `mymat.at<double>(0, 0)` to watch but there are two problems:

- Sometimes it doesn't work: `Couldn't find method cv::Mat::at<double>`
- Even if it works, it is very hard to check elements one by one.

Currently, I write Mat contents to a file using `cv::FileStorage` but it is not a good solution also.

Is there any VSCode extension like [Image Watch](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualCPPTeam.ImageWatch2019) to show value of Mat elements while debugging?

Comment: VSCode supports Natvis (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/natvis), if you use VC, you get full support for Natvis and a subset for g++/clang (that might be sufficient for your use case). You can check this Natvis for OpenCV for instance: https://github.com/cdcseacave/Visual-Studio-Visualizers/blob/master/OpenCV.natvis

Answer (score 0):

If you are currently using GDB to debug your application, you may wish to refer to [this open source project](https://github.com/OpenImageDebugger/OpenImageDebugger),and it is not currently available as a plugin for vscode.

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)